# How to rename a model field from default Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I would like to rename all the Groups field in Django admin as Roles field. But there are still some parts that didn't changed.

I have successfully renamed Groups into Roles using this code (models.py):

```
class Role(Group):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'auth'
        verbose_name = _('role')
        verbose_name_plural = _('roles')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

but then a field in the Users still has the name 'Groups' in it.
[Please see screenshot attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvBD4.png)

I know it has something to do with the PermissionsMixin in ***django.contrib.auth.models*** which contains the ManyToManyField named groups that is being called in the UserAdmin.

```
class PermissionsMixin(models.Model):
    ...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    ...
```

I would like to know how to rename this model field.

**Edit:**
Here is the code for the UserAdmin:

```
    class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
        form = UserAdminChangeForm
        add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

        list_display = ('username',)
        fieldsets = (
            (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password',)}),
            (None, {'fields': ('groups',)}),
        )
        add_fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2')}
            ),
        )
        filter_horizontal = ('groups',)
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you are referring to.

Comment: Hi Sir @CalebGoodman! I have added the code I'm referring to.

Comment: thanks.  I'm looking into this now.  Can you show me the code you use to generate the image?  I'm familiar with django, just not the admin package.

Comment: @CalebGoodman I've edited it again Sir. Hope its clearer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly do not want to rename the model field, but simply change the label in the admin. You can achieve that by customizing the admin form. Something along the following lines should do the trick:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # ...
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        kwargs['labels'] = {'groups': 'roles'}
        return super().get_form(request, obj=obj, change=change, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir it worked. However, I would also like to change the label in the filter field (from 'Available groups' to 'Available roles' and 'Chosen groups' to 'Chosen roles') and I don't know if there's also a way to simply change it without modifying the django's default model field.